# Strange UIImageview remote image loading behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am trying to load remote image on my imageview using the following code. displayImage is referenced with imageview at testview.xib

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.displayImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.gImg.URL];

    NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    self.originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.displayImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.displayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.originalImage];
    [self.displayImage setImage:self.originalImage];

    NSLog(@"DisplayImage Object:%@",self.displayImage);

    NSLog(@"height of Displayimage image:%.f",self.displayImage.image.size.height);
}
```

But the image is not showing. I am certain image did loaded on imageview. Here is output log:

```
DisplayImage Object:<UIImageView: 0x11033270; frame = (0 0; 720 632); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1104c620>>
height of Displayimage image:632
```

Comment: Once you've set your image with imageWithData, save the image to the filepath in the app bundle.

Comment: Do you ever add `displayImage` as a subview of your main view?

Comment: Is data coming in imagedata ?

Comment: Put log for self.originalImage

Comment: setimage fixed the problem. Thanks and thumbs up everybody for your kind response. Answer picked based upon oldest response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dispatch queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t  backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mayapp", NULL);
```

Use `NSData` method `dataWithContentsOfURL` and download the image in a background thread:

```
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:requestWithBodyParams];
        //as soon as the image is downloaded, draw image in a main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        self.originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        self.displayImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.displayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.originalImage];
        [self.displayImage setImage:self.originalImage];

});//close main block    
});//background block
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I am modified your code:
No need to alloc the UIImageView in code, if you have the **UIImageView in .xib.**

```
NSURL *gImg = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vinfotech.com/sites/default/files/iphoe-app-design-ios7-way-12.jpg"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:gImg];

    NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];

         UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
          self.displayImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        //  self.displayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
                 [self.displayImage setImage:originalImage];

         NSLog(@"DisplayImage Object:%@",self.displayImage);    
                 NSLog(@"height of Displayimage image:%.f",self.displayImage.image.size.height);
```

Hope so, this code helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This Sample code works fine for me :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iceclearmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/SEO-and-url-Shorteners.jpg"];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] ;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [self.imagedownload setImage:image]; //UIImageView
}
```